# PyQT5: How to interactively paint on image within QLabel Widget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter, qlabel, qpixmap

Python 3, latest version of PyQt5 on Mac OS Mojave

I want a PyQt5 program in which the user could paint connected dots on an image (click distinctively and the points are automatically connected). It is important that I can only draw on the image in the QLabel widget (or an alternative widget) and not over the entire main window.

I can plot the image and get the the coordinates of the previous two clicks but when I want to paint on the image it happens underneath the image. Further I have troubles in getting the coordinates as input for my paintevent.

```
class Example(QWidget):

   def __init__(self):

      super().__init__()


      title = "Darcy"
      top = 400
      left = 400
      width = 550
      height = 600

      self.clickcount = 0
      self.x = 0
      self.y = 0



      self.setWindowTitle(title)
      self.setGeometry(top,left, width, height)

      self.initUI()

  def paintEvent(self, e):

      qp = QPainter()
      qp.begin(self)
      self.drawLines(qp)
      qp.end()


  def drawLines(self, qp):

      pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)

      qp.setPen(pen)
      qp.drawLine(20, 40, 250, 40)

  def initUI(self):

      self.map = QLabel()
      Im = QPixmap("GM_loc.png")
      Im = Im.scaled(450,450)
      self.map.setPixmap(Im)

      self.loc = QLabel()
      self.test = QLabel()

      self.map.mousePressEvent = self.getPos



      #organize in grid
      grid = QGridLayout()
      grid.setSpacing(10)

      grid.addWidget(self.map, 0, 0)
      grid.addWidget(self.loc,1,0)
      grid.addWidget(self.test,2,0)

      self.setLayout(grid)
      self.show()


  def getPos(self , event):

      self.clickcount += 1

      self.x_old = self.x
      self.y_old = self.y

      self.x = event.pos().x()
      self.y = event.pos().y() 


      self.loc.setText("x = "+str(self.x)+" & y= "+str(self.y)+" & old x = " + str(self.x_old) + " & old y = " + str(self.y_old))


 if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance!
PS I am a rookie in PyQt5 so any hints in more efficient code are more than welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class MyScribbling(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penOn = QAction(QIcon('Image/ok.png'), 'ON   drawing', self)
        self.penOn.triggered.connect(self.drawingOn)
        self.penOff = QAction(QIcon('Image/exit.png'), 'OFF drawing', self)
        self.penOff.triggered.connect(self.drawingOff)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        toolbar.addAction(self.penOn)
        toolbar.addAction(self.penOff)

        self.scribbling = False
        self.myPenColor = Qt.red      
        self.myPenWidth = 3           

        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        self.image     = QPixmap("Image/picture.png")
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.setWindowTitle("drawing On / Off")

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if (event.button() == Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribbling: 
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribbling:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth, 
                                Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def drawingOn(self):
        self.scribbling = True

    def drawingOff(self):
        self.scribbling = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyScribbling()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post the same answer several times, if the answer is the same for both questions that implies that the question is duplicated, and you should mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but this does not solve my problem. It is important that it is still within the QLabel widget and now the image to draw on is spread over my entire main window + I don't need a brush but the possibility to click and get points which are corrected (like drawing a polygon)